# Cannot login in VirtualBox 7.0 Windows 10 because vboxuser password expired

Tags: windows-10

I installed a Windows 10 system on Virtual Box 7.0, in a Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

When I installed Windows 10, a user named "vboxuser" was automatically created and I began to use it.

Now, when I try login, I received a message indicating that the password has expired and that I should enter another one, but it asks for the old one that I don't know what it is. The password field was always blank.

I also tried to sign in with my Microsoft account but I get the wrong password warning (when it's not wrong).

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is off topic. Hover over the virtualbox tag and read that popup.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When installing Windows using the wizard in Virtualbox, the default password for vboxuser is changeme
(at least in my case. using virtualbox 7.0.4)